# electron builder change install directory - referencing environmenal variable from within installer.nsh

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am creating an electron app installer using electron-builder. I can change the default installation directory using a macro in build/installer.nsh as follows:

```
!macro preInit
 SetRegView 64
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\myApp"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\myApp"
 SetRegView 32
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\myApp"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\myApp"
!macroend
```

This works for me and my app can install under C:\myApp .

However, I would like for it to install under C:\USER_HOME_DIR\myApp. I have tried using "$(HOME)\myApp", "${HOME}\myApp", "%HOME%\myApp" to no avail. I feel like I am missing something simple in how to reference the evironmental variable pointing to the user's home directory but don't know how.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the home folder location is in the `%HOMEPATH%` variable, not `%HOME%`. Try that instead.

Comment: I used "%HOMEPATH%\myApp" but it created a literal "%HOMEPATH% directory into which it installed the application. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The NSIS constant for the user directory is: `$PROFILE`

So the following code should work:

```
!macro preInit
    SetRegView 64
    WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$PROFILE\MyApp"
    WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$PROFILE\MyApp"
    SetRegView 32
    WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$PROFILE\MyApp"
    WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$PROFILE\MyApp"
!macroend
```